# Angular dependency injection, which is the better attempt and what's the difference?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with angular for some time nowm and when I read examples or tutorials, I always see two ways of how they inject their services into their controllers.

What's the major difference between the following 2 methods?

1.

```
.controller('MyController', ['myService', function(myService) {
}]);
```

2.

```
.controller('MyController', function(myService) {
});
```

I include the services at the first line of the controller JS file:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.services']);
```

Comment: The no. 1 or the one with the brackets is the safest way to declare your controller, services, directives, etc. Especially when you make your js to its minified version. While the no. 2 will cause an error when you try to minify your js codes.

Comment: Another question from another lazy developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st style is [officially recommended](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/guide/di).

But the 2nd usage also has its own advantage:

> One advantage of this approach is that there's no array of names to keep in sync with the function parameters. You can also freely reorder dependencies.

and you can also fix the minify problem with tools like [gulp-ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate)

As both usages are described and supported by AngularJS, I think you can freely choose either of them, only remember to keep it through out the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider your implementations always for production.
The first method is correct because, maybe you'll use *myService* only in *myController* and strict injection is a good choise.

The second method is not good for maintenance and legibility. Why inject all services of myApp.services in myApp?

Finally, second method could cause some error on build phase (minify).

Enjoy AngularJS.